# How to cope with state flows in UML?

Tags: uml, finite-state-machine

I got a few questions about using UML state machines in software architecture:

I have to design an STM and express it as part of a UML model. There is a singelton STM Maintainer holding the instance of the STM and  performing state transitions. There is also an STM User class, reading the value - the currently active state - of the STM.

1. How to express which class or component is responsible for maintaining an instance of the STM? In other words: How to express the STM Maintainer dependency on the STM design?
2. How to express the information flow of the current state of the single instance of a state machine from the STM Maintainer to STM user classes?

Currently I am designing the STM together with an enumeration named after the STM, both owned by the STM maintainer component. And I add an information flow from the STM Maintainer to the STM User class, conveying that enum.

But the redundancy of the STM design and the enum values feels not correct. Some observations:

- The details of the STM should be known model wide, as the STM
  Maintainer just has to maintain an instance, not owning the design
- The dependency of the enum on the STM design is not formally expressed and
  maintenance could lead to errors if you miss the synchronization of
  the enum values with the state names.
- The implementer of an STM User class formally does not get a hint to
  look at the STM when using the enum.
- ...

Hint to information flow:
I use information flows as high-level constructs that need a stereotype. The stereotype defines how the flow is actually performed. E.g. in case of AUTOSAR I have a Sender-Receiver and a Client-Server stereotype for information flows.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You implemented an STM based on enums and you got asked to map your code to UML diagrams. Am I right? If yes. What's the core of your question? The "correctness" of the implementation or finding diagrams for it?

Answer (score 1):

Whether the state is internal to one object, or about a set of several object s (e.g. subsystem) is not specified in the state diagram itself. But you can document the **context** of the state machine (e.g. class, component, collaboration) if it has one. This defines then the relevant triggers for the state transition, as explained in the UML 2.5.1 specifications:

> If the StateMachine has a kind of BehavioredClassifier context, then that Classifier defines which Signal and CallEvent triggers are applicable to that StateMachine, and which Features are available to the Behaviors owned by the StateMachine. Signal Triggers and CallEvent Triggers for the StateMachine are defined according to the Receptions and Operations of this Classifier respectively. These Features may be used to define message event Triggers of the StateMachine.

But this does not necessarily imply that the context is responsible to maintain the state machine.

In UML there's no information flow between states, but **transitions** between states.
"Information flows" should be modelelled in different kind of diagrams (e.g. sequence diagram or communication diagrams for exchange of messages between instances of classes; or activity diagrams for object flows).

Comment: 1. What would you do to express that a certain STM is owned by a class or in case of several objects owned by the composition class where all objects belong to?
2. For sure, I am only interested in information flows between classes, e.g. the owner of a STM and the user.

Comment: 1. Class diagram, 2. Collaboration diagram.  For lower level details, 2a. Sequence Diagram, but depending on the STM the sequence diagram can become unreadable. if the STM represents the state of a business process that goes through several phase (stages), then BPM diagrams

Comment: @ngong I've edited to clarify 1.  For 2, sequence or communication diagrams seem appropriate,  if the exchanges are not too complex.

Comment: It looks like you cited the middle block in your answer from somewhere - obviously not from the OPs post. Any reference?

Comment: @DocBrown Ah! Sorry. It was the UML specs. Answer edited accordingly

Comment: This answer bypasses my question. Situation: Class A maintains a state machine. It is not private. Class B needs to know about the current state. I'd like to model an Information Flow from A to B where the Conveyed Item is the state machine or an instance thereof. This seems not to be possible with the current UML spec, if I am right.

Comment: do you mean that class A owns the state machine or that it is the context of the state machine?

Answer (score 0):

If the *owner* of the statemachine is a *behaviored classifier*, it is its *context* and thus "responsible for maintaining an instance of it". Actually, I would rather speak of the statemachine as *describing* the behavior of the classifier.

UML allows to define a statemachine without context, but leaves it open, what this should mean. If the owner for example is a package, the context is empty. I think it just means, that the modeler didn't want to be so specific.

Two classes, that know of each other can find out about the state of the other class. Of course, since UML doesn't include an expression language, it is up to your tool to define how this is done.

The cameo simulation engine for example allows to use `ALH.inState(a,'A')`. See my example here:
[image]

This allows B to check the state of A. If you want A to be active, you can create entry-behaviors, that send a signal to B to inform it about the current state. Your enumeration could be useful as payload for this signal, or you could have a different signal for each of the states.

I wonder, how you do this with information flows? They don't have execution semantics. If you don't need execution, why not simply use an information item `currentstate`.